# Her eyes ate me

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I sipped my drink. I like an effect as well as the next fellow. Her eyes ate me.

It's from 'Red Wind' by Raymond Chandler.
Seemingly well-known phrase, but what exactly it mean?

1. The narrator was fascinated by the beauty of her eyes?
2. Or she was devouring her scrutinizingly?

Answer (score 2):

The sense of this depends on the fact that this comes as a pause in the narrator character speaking to another character. So "I sipped my drink. I like an effect as well as the next fellow" means that he's deliberately pausing to drink for the effect it has on her. "Her eyes ate me" mean they are looking at him with widely and intently, the image being that they are almost going to suck him in and devour him.

In this context therefore it indicates her eagerness to hear the rest of what he has to say. In another context it could indicate eagerness for the speaker sexually, or for the speaker to do something else other than continue a story.

Comment: Or it could be his imagination. ;)